# Do some code only while a button has a specific value attribute

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that acts like a pump, so it will execute code only while a button has an 'on' value. I've done the following but this just gets locked in a loop, could someone help, thanks

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="intruc" class="instructions">Instructions go in here</div>
    <input type="button" value="On" id="onoff" onclick="pump();">
    <div id="moniac"></div>

</div>

<script>

function pump(button) {
    console.log("pump");
    currentvalue = document.getElementById('onoff').value;
    if(currentvalue == "Off"){
        document.getElementById("onoff").value="On";
        currentvalue == "On"
        run(currentvalue)
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("onoff").value="Off";
        currentvalue == "Off"
        run(currentvalue)
    }
}

function run(status) {
    console.log("run");
    console.log(status);
    if (status==="On"){
        console.log("do all the code")
        run(status)
    }

}





</script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for mousedown event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mousedown

Comment: I think you shouldn't use `currentvalue == Off` or `on` instead use `currentvalue = Off` or `on`....also your last run function dont need

Comment: moniac, pump() ? Are you creating a Phillips machine?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the `mousedown` event, I made a clean demo which you can adapt in your code:

**HTML**

```
<button id="run">Off</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var runCode = false;
var button = document.getElementById("run");

function pump() 
{
    if (runCode) {
        /** Code to run, when on. **/
        button.innerText = "Off";
        runCode = false;
    } else {
        button.innerText = "On";
        runCode = true;   
    }
}

button.addEventListener("mousedown", pump);
```

The "flag" `runCode` determines if the code should run or not.

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/coea3ckb/2/

**Edit 1**

You are assigning that value incorrectly, you are using `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper way of doing something like this would include using **intervals**.

You can read about those here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval
(You can also find information on w3schools, but I rather recommend MDN.)

You could do something like this:
(the two files need to be in the same directory)

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pump</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="intructions" class="instructions">Instructions go in here</div>
        <input id="pumpToggleButton" type="button" value="OFF">
        <div id="pumpOutput">0</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## scripts.js

```
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

var pumpToggleButton;

var pumpValue = 0, pumpState = false, pumpInterval;

var pumpFrequency = 100;

function init() {
  pumpToggleButton = document.getElementById("pumpToggleButton");
  pumpToggleButton.addEventListener("click", pumpToggle, false);
}

function pumpAction() {
  pumpValue += 5;
  document.getElementById("pumpOutput").innerHTML = pumpValue;
}

function pumpToggle() {
  pumpState = !pumpState;

  pumpToggleButton.value = pumpState ? "ON" : "OFF";

  if (pumpState) {
    pumpInterval = setInterval(pumpAction, pumpFrequency);
  } else {
    clearInterval(pumpInterval);
  }
}
```

As you can see, I also recommend assigning the function to the button with an event listener instead of the old `onload="action()"` way.

(More info on that here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
and here is why you should use it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener )

ps.: I tried to use jsfiddle and codepen, but they don't seem to handle event listeners too well...

Answer (score 0):

I made your code work . Just make these changes:

```
   <div id="main">
    <div id="intruc" class="instructions">Instructions go in here</div>
    <input type="button" value="On" id="onoff" onclick="pump();">
    <div id="moniac"></div>

</div>

<script>

function pump() { 

    currentvalue = document.getElementById('onoff').value;
    if(currentvalue == "On"){
        document.getElementById("onoff").value="Off";
        show();

    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("onoff").value="On";
       return false;
    }
}



function show()
{

alert(' your code which you want to repeat');


show();
}
</script>
```

You can use window variable as a checker for `show();` to work or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys but both these don't tell me how to make the function repeatedly loop through the code in them whilst the button is on. They only do it the once...or am I just thick and missing something here? (you don't have to answer the last bit)

Comment: why you want to repeatedly loop through the code . You wanted a part of code to run only if the pressed button value is ON .... and that is happening now..... now what else ?

Comment: I want it to act like water being pumped around a loop. while the button  is on the code in the function get executed repeatedly and things happen, ie water in different parts of the loop will do different things depending on what levers are pulled. When the button is switched off then water stops flowing around the loop ( the code stops executing repeatedly) and everything stops

Comment: Ok show the code which you want to execute repeatedly,,,,than we can decide how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I just edited your entire code, now it's work

```js
function pump() {
    console.log("pump");
    currentvalue = document.getElementById('onoff').value;
    if(currentvalue == "Off"){
        document.getElementById("onoff").value="On";
        //currentvalue = "On"
        //run(currentvalue)
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("onoff").value="Off";
        currentvalue == "Off"
        //run(currentvalue)
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="intruc" class="instructions">Instructions go in here</div>
    <input type="button" value="On" id="onoff" onclick="pump();">
    <div id="moniac"></div>

</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59cj0nf6/) ( But not work correctly on fiddle , test it on local)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that uses [data-attribute(s)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for the pump button value: https://jsfiddle.net/ahvonenj/pL9qf5mq/

```
document.getElementById('pumpbutton').addEventListener('click', pump);

function pump()
{
    var pumpState = this.dataset.value;

    if(pumpState === 'true')
    {
        this.dataset.value = 'false';
        this.value = 'OFF';
    }
    else
    {
        this.dataset.value = 'true';
        this.value = 'ON';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for there input, I decided to use the setInterval function to execute the function I needed. In this example I've got it set to every three seconds for testing but would have it running much faster on final piece. My solution looks like this:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="intruc" class="instructions">Instructions go in here</div>
    <input type="button" value="Off" id="onoff" html="Turn on" onclick="onOff();">
</div>

<script>

var switchStatus=document.getElementById('onoff').value;
console.log("Switch status at the start= ",switchStatus)
var run = setInterval(function(){ pump(switchStatus) }, 3000);

function onOff() {
    console.log("onOff");
    switchStatus=document.getElementById('onoff').value;
    if(switchStatus =="Off"){
        document.getElementById("onoff").value="On";
        switchStatus = "On"
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("onoff").value="Off";
        switchStatus = "Off"
    }
}

function pump(status) {
    console.log("pump");
    console.log(status);
    if (status=="On"){
        console.log("do all the code")

    }

}
```